# Using a MacBook Pro for .NET development

Tags: windows-7, macos, vmware-fusion, visual-studio-2010, parallels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MacBook Pro for Windows development via virtualization. Performance?](https://superuser.com/questions/132445/macbook-pro-for-windows-development-via-virtualization-performance)

I am wondering if using a MacBook Pro 15 (2.66 Ghz i7, High Res Anti Glare, Custom SSD, 8 GB RAM) for .NET development (as well as the occasional dabble into Xcode for iPhone coding) makes sense?

**I love the hardware.** I already have a 24" screen which I can attach to the MBP via Display Port when I feel the need for more screen space.

Will running Visual Studio 2010 (and its successor) via VMWare Fusion/Parallels hinder the performance by a noticeable margin?

Hoping to make an informed decision.

PS: Will be buying (if at all) once the refresh is out (with Sandy Bridge processors)

Comment: Dupe [MacBook Pro for Windows development via virtualization. Performance? ](http://superuser.com/questions/132445/macbook-pro-for-windows-development-via-virtualization-performance)

Comment: [This topic might also help](http://superuser.com/questions/231266/getting-more-performance-out-of-a-macbook-pro).

Comment: My bad... only after creating this question I saw the related threads. Thanks for helping out guys.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a mid-2008 MBP for fairly heavy SQL Server and .Net development using VMWare Fusion.  I've had no performance issues at all, just give the VM as much RAM as you can.  I really don't notice any difference than running on a dedicated Windows box.